# Avoid boxing & unboxing in generic class

Tags: c#, generics, boxing, unboxing

Below is some quick code to illustrate my question.  Any way to avoid this apparently unnecessary boxing/unboxing?

```
public class TestClass<T>
{
  public T TestMethod()
  {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
    {
      return true; // doesn't work
      return (T)(object)true; // works, but any way to avoid this?
    }

    return default(T);
  }
}
```

Comment: Generics mean "same code works for multiple types". You want different code for different types, so your use-case is outside the focus of generics.

Comment: If you're just going to check the type in the body of the method why make it generic in the first place?

Comment: Does the .NET runtime not optimize that out?

Comment: @dtb, @Servy: It's something similar to LINQ's `Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)`, but with a few custom cases such as "Y"/"N" needing manual conversion to true/false.  If bool were my own type I could use an explicit operator.  All the other types are handled generically.

Comment: @TravisGockel: That may very well be true, but then it could only do it for the `TestClass<bool>` version of the generic.

Comment: Casting `Func` is the way. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45507393

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the only way to handle what you are doing here (returning a non default value for a specific closed generic type).

Comment: This is what I figured since T isn't known at compile time, but I thought I would try.  :)

Answer (score -1):

Make it a static field.

```
public class TestClass<T>
{
  static T TrueIfBoolean = typeof(T) == typeof(bool) ? (T)(object)true : default(T)

  public T TestMethod()
  {
    return TrueIfBoolean;
  }
}
```

That way, the boxing/unboxing only happens once. It's also entirely possible that this kind of optimisation is done by the runtime anyway even in your initial code.

Comment: I don't think the compiler is allowed to optimize away a cast from a value type to `object`.  On the other hand, if the cast only happens once, the time wasted is going to be a non-factor.