# Primitive type conversion in generic method without boxing

Tags: c#, boxing

While doing some profiling on one of our applications, I found this code:

```
public TOut GetValue<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn> getter)
{
    var value = getter();

    // Do some stuff with the value

    return (TOut)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(TOut));
}
```

`TIn` and `TOut` are either int, double, or string.

This showed up in the profiling sessions as an important source of heap allocations because of the boxing when using int or double. The input value of `Convert.ChangeType` is boxed because the method expects an object, and the return value is boxed for the same reason.

I'm trying to optimize this code because this method is used in a high-throughput service, where this kind of allocation is prohibitive. Ideally, I would have rewritten the method as non-generic, but the API is widely used by various teams and a refactoring of such scale will take months. In the meantime I'm trying to mitigate the issue and find a way to improve the situation without changing the API contract. However I've been struggling on this for a while and have yet to find a solution.

Do you know a way, even ugly, to handle the int -> double and double -> int conversion without boxing, given the method contract? Note that I can't change the parameters but I could add a generic constraint (such as `where TIn : IConvertible`, but this hasn't helped me much).

Comment: In other words you want generic `ChangeType`? You can use ["switch/case"](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,348) for all types you care and otherwise call boxed version.

Comment: Maybe taking a look at the [.NET referencesource for Convert.ChangeType](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,dc591cb7008278c6) will help in understanding what it does, perhaps allowing you to create a shorter/faster/more efficient approach for your specific scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390286/generic-parse-method-without-boxing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need to specialize a couple of conversions, I think the following works and does not incur any per-call allocations:

```
    private static int FromDouble(double other)
    {
        return (int)other;
    }
    private static double FromInt(int other)
    {
        return (double)other;
    }

    private static Func<double, int> di = FromDouble;
    private static Func<int, double> id = FromInt;
    public TOut GetValue<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn> getter)
    {
        var value = getter();

        // Do some stuff with the value

        if (typeof(TIn) == typeof(int) && typeof(TOut) == typeof(double))
        {
            var gf = (Func<TIn, TOut>)(object)id;
            return gf(value);
        }else if (typeof(TIn) == typeof(double) && typeof(TOut) == typeof(int))
        {
            var gf = (Func<TIn, TOut>)(object)di;
            return gf(value);
        }

        return (TOut)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(TOut));
    }
```

There are a couple of further tweaks that could be made to this, of course.

Comment: I didn't think of casting a delegate, that's smart. Thanks!

Comment: Wow nice. It took me while to understand this code, but once I did - it clicked. The readability suffers though. Well, I guess it always does when you're optimizing stuff at this level.

PS. I'm having a similar issue - saving stuff to Redis.

Comment: This is a cool trick! +1